# Issues animating a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some issues with animating a button. First I made the buttons appear after the window was loaded with this code:

`$(window).on('load',() => {
// console.log("content loaded")
  $('.button').delay(1000).fadeIn(3000)
  });`

This did what I wanted, fade in after 1 second. Then I made some CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000; 
  border: 3px solid rgb(48, 48, 48);
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin:0 5px;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: :3px solid rgb(35, 35, 35);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  transition: ease 1s;
}
```

And I have this HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button" id="">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="">Ex. 1</button>
</div>
```

With this CSS the buttons don't fade in anymore and just popup after 1 second. Any ideas what caused this or did I do something stupid (probably the case :D)?

Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this using opacity :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.button').delay(1000).fadeTo( "slow", 1 );
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
opacity:0;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000; 
  border: 3px solid rgb(48, 48, 48);
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin:0 5px;
  transition:1s ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: :3px solid rgb(35, 35, 35);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  transition: ease 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button" id="">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="">Ex. 1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea I just found out that `transition:1s ease-in-out;` causes problems in my code. But your solution to use opacity works perfectly! Thanks for your time, really helped me out!

Comment: youre wellcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

I made a small change to the js. Hope this is what you wanted

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log("content loaded")
 $('.button').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.button').fadeIn(3000);
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000; 
  border: 3px solid rgb(48, 48, 48);
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin:0 5px;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: :3px solid rgb(35, 35, 35);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  transition: ease 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button" id="id">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="id">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="id">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="id">Ex. 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="id">Ex. 1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the animation what I want after it faded in, But I really like to make it so that it doesn't show and after a couple of seconds fade in. but you are really close!

Comment: Can u please repharse; what am i missing?

Comment: Let me say it like this:
1. show buttons after a delay of 1 second
2. then the buttons hover animation needs to work

however your code didn't show the button after a delay of 1 second, I had the same problem as you. But still thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

All the button element have same id value. Id should be unique per element.

Comment: I know, I did that so I could copy paste the buttons and see the result of the animations. The buttons don't have funtions yet. Just edited it out!